# Unable to communicate with peripheral over Serial USB from Linux

Tags: linux, python, serial-port

I am struggling with establishing comunications with a peripheral over USB serial on my Linux here (fedora 20/64bit), and I am probably missing some step:

I connect the device, a /dev/ttyUSBx port correctly shows up. I use python/pySerial do to drive it and instead of the answers the device should give me, all I can read from the serial port is a single zero byte ("\x00") each time the connection is reset.

I've tried different serial-to-USB adapters, different serial cables, and even different peripherals (and models) at the other end. With the windows based closed-source programs that communicate with the peripheral everything seems to work nice.

Here is a typical session of what I am trying:

```
>>> import serial
>>> s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", timeout=.1)
>>> 
>>> s.flush()
>>> s.write("(&S)")
4
>>> s.read()
'\x00'
>>>
```

(instead of "\x00" here, I should get a several character lenght string as a response. (the device answers correctly to the same protocol over TCP/IP) .

Am I missing some configuration step on the serial port? 
Here is my setserial output for it:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0, Flags: low_latency
```

And the Pyserial configuration:

```
Serial<id=0x7f525c5daf10, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0.1, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

(these parameters are the same that are shown on the serial port that  is configured on Windows where the device works - but for the timeout)

Comment: The problem with USB to serial is that USB is 8-pin and serial is 9-pins. Unless you have device driver that let's you configure which pin corresponds with which pin of serial, you may not have access to all the PINs which is causing an issue.

Comment: The hardware I have do work with proprietary software that comes with the external device (using the same Serial to USB connector). I also have the device protocol, which could be incomplete - but I think something is missing at port configuration time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it - 
I had to check with he device vendor - and it is a matter of the settings of the device on the protocol - 
One has to use the serial port with DTR active, and RTS inactive - these might be obvious tries for one used with the hardware side, but not so for developers used to higher level coding.

The fact that fooled me is that with little documentation on what is what, I mistook the `rtsdtr` and `rtscts` parameters on the Python's PySerial Serial object with the actual DTR and RTS pin setting - and changing these two achieved nothing.

Calling the methods

```
serial_.setDTR(True)
serial_.setRTS(False)
```

is what actually sets the pins on the port, and make communication possible with this device.